# Firestore won't read \n on a jspdf string

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a new line on a jspdf string. Problem is firestore won't recognize it ( \n ) as a line break but as a string.

Solutions I've tried:

\n\n , html br tag

```
var string = "This is a sample lb\n text"
var string1 = string.replace("lb","\n")

doc.text(10,10, string1)
```

```
actual : This is a sample lb\n text

expected : This is a sample 
           text
```

Comment: So far I know a firebase doc can only read string integers or date/time and some other formats. doc.text will always respond with a string at this point. You can just store the string and and put it back to the jsonpdf I assume.

Comment: Yes tried it and it still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Firestore SDKs don't have an issue with new lines, so the issue must be somewhere else in your code. To demonstrate, I ran the below code that wrote a string into a document, retrieved it, then displayed the result:

[image: Chrome DevTools console demonstrating correct new line handling]

Code:

```
db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("lines").doc("newline").set({'myString': "This is a new\nline"});
x = db.collection("lines").doc("newline").get();
x.then(function(doc) {console.log(doc.data().myString)});
```